# Need Help About the Xml File generated by my code

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-mvc

Below is my controller Code which generate the XML file and save this file and specific location

```
List<propertyfile> data = ws.GetPropertyFiles();
            XmlDocument writer = new XmlDocument();
            // Create XML declaration
            XmlNode declaration = writer.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, null, null);
            writer.AppendChild(declaration);
            // Make the root element first
            XmlElement root = writer.CreateElement("Channel");
            writer.AppendChild(root);
            //XmlElement rot = writer.CreateElement("item");
            //writer.AppendChild(rot);
            //Server.MapPath   //HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") 
            string wallFolderPath = Server.MapPath("~/assets/wall/");
            var newGuid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            string filename = wallFolderPath+ "wallview_" +newGuid+".xml";
            var pathlocal = ServerUrlPath+"assets/wall/" + "wallview_" + newGuid + ".xml";
            ViewBag.wallpath = pathlocal;
            System.IO.File.Create(filename).Dispose();

            foreach (var a in data)
            {
                if (a.Path != null && a.ThumbnailPath != null)
                {
                    XmlElement id = writer.CreateElement("item");
                    XmlElement name = writer.CreateElement("title");
                    name.InnerText = a.Name;
                    XmlElement age = writer.CreateElement("media:description");
                    var e_path = a.Path;
                    XmlElement anchor = writer.CreateElement("a");
                    e_path = e_path.Substring(2, e_path.Length - 2);
                    e_path= ServerUrlPath + e_path;
                    anchor.SetAttribute("href", e_path);
                    age.AppendChild(anchor);
                    //age.SetAttribute("href", e_path);
                    XmlElement linq = writer.CreateElement("link");
                    var e_linq = a.Path;
                    e_linq = e_linq.Substring(2, e_linq.Length - 2);
                    linq.InnerText = ServerUrlPath + e_linq;
                    XmlElement thumb = writer.CreateElement("media:thumbnail");
                    var e_thumbnail = a.ThumbnailPath;
                    e_thumbnail = e_thumbnail.Substring(2, e_thumbnail.Length - 2);
                    e_thumbnail = ServerUrlPath + e_thumbnail;
                    thumb.SetAttribute("url", e_thumbnail);
                    XmlElement content = writer.CreateElement("media:content");
                    content.SetAttribute("url", e_thumbnail);
                    id.AppendChild(name);
                    id.AppendChild(age);
                    id.AppendChild(linq);
                    id.AppendChild(thumb);
                    id.AppendChild(content);
                    root.AppendChild(id);
                    writer.AppendChild(root);
                }
            }
            writer.Save(filename);
```

Result(XML File Generated)

```
<Channel>
<item>
<title>RedbrushAlpha.png</title>
<description>
<a href="http://localhost:2023/Files/aa1989f3-f4bd-489d-abca-b0c7cdfa4ae7.png"/>
</description>
<link>
http://localhost:2023/Files/aa1989f3-f4bd-489d-abca-b0c7cdfa4ae7.png
</link>
<thumbnail url="http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/aa1989f3-f4bd-489d-abca-b0c7cdfa4ae7.Jpeg"/>
<content url="http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/aa1989f3-f4bd-489d-abca-b0c7cdfa4ae7.Jpeg"/>
</item>
```

**But I Need file generate similar to this with rss tag and  tag like  Below is the xml file code and i need to create file similar to this**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
 <channel>
    <item>
    <title>mastercard.png</title>
    <media:description>&lt;a href=' http://localhost:2023/Files/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.png'</media:description>
    <link>http://localhost:2023/Files/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.png</link>
    <media:thumbnail url="http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.Jpeg" />
    <media:content url="http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.Jpeg" />
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Have you already tried SyndicationFeed class? Take a look at it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx . Regards.

Answer (score 0):

hi please check updated code with some changes you will now get expect output

you just need to update value of tag and your output will be ready

```
XmlDocument writer = new XmlDocument();


// Create XML declaration
XmlNode declaration = writer.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration, null, null);
writer.AppendChild(declaration);


//add rss node over here
XmlElement rssElement = writer.CreateElement("rss");
rssElement.SetAttribute("version", "2.0");
rssElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:media", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
rssElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

//Channel
XmlElement channelElement = writer.CreateElement("Channel");

XmlElement itemElement = writer.CreateElement("item");

//title
XmlElement titleElement = writer.CreateElement("title");
titleElement.InnerText = "mastercard.png";
itemElement.AppendChild(titleElement);


//media:description
XmlElement media_DescriptionElement = writer.CreateElement("media", "description", "media:description");
media_DescriptionElement.InnerText = "&lt;a href=' http://localhost:2023/Files/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.png";
itemElement.AppendChild(media_DescriptionElement);


//link
XmlElement linkElement = writer.CreateElement("link");
linkElement.InnerText = "http://localhost:2023/Files/aa1989f3-f4bd-489d-abca-b0c7cdfa4ae7.png";
itemElement.AppendChild(linkElement);

//media:thumbnail
XmlElement media_ThumbnailElement = writer.CreateElement("media", "thumbnail", "media:thumbnail");
media_ThumbnailElement.SetAttribute("url", "http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.Jpeg");
itemElement.AppendChild(media_ThumbnailElement);

//media:content
XmlElement media_ContentElement = writer.CreateElement("media", "content", "media:content");
media_ContentElement.SetAttribute("url", "http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.Jpeg");
itemElement.AppendChild(media_ContentElement);

channelElement.AppendChild(itemElement);
rssElement.AppendChild(channelElement);
writer.AppendChild(rssElement);
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Channel>
        <item>
            <title>mastercard.png</title>
            <media:description xmlns:media="media:description">&amp;lt;a href=' http://localhost:2023/Files/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.png</media:description>
            <link>http://localhost:2023/Files/aa1989f3-f4bd-489d-abca-b0c7cdfa4ae7.png</link>
            <media:thumbnail url="http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.Jpeg" xmlns:media="media:thumbnail" />
            <media:content url="http://localhost:2023/FilesThumbs/054ee47b-7ecf-42d1-bfcc-06ac5f84b6d4.Jpeg" xmlns:media="media:content" />
        </item>
    </Channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: try now its updated code and it's  working perfectly as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Well, first and foremost, although it doesn't really change anything, it's important to realize that both `XDocument` and `XElement` accepts `params`, i.e. a list of items to add. This will make your code *much* more readable. For example:

```
var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("root",
        new XElement("foo"),
        new XElement("bar")
    );
 );
```

That way the hierarchy is very clear, and you're not throwing variables all over the place.

Second, you literally made your root `<channel>`, rather than `<rss>`, so simply make `<rss>` your root element in your `XDocument` and then add `<channel>` to that, rather than directly to the `XDocument` as you're doing now.

Third, you can add attributes to elements using `XAttribute`. However, for namespaces, you want to persist these in a variable, so you can utilize them later as you're building your XML document. For example:

```
var media = XNamespace.Get("http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/");
var atom = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");

var xdoc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("rss",
        new XAttribute("version", "2.0"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "media", media),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "atom", atom),
        new XElement("channel",
            ...
        )
     )
);
```

Then, when you need to use one of these namespaces, you concatentate it to the element name. For example, with `media:thumbnail`:

```
new XElement(media + "thumbnail",
    new XAttribute("url", e_thumbnail)
)
```

Finally, if you use `ToString` on the `XDocument`, it will strip the XML declaration, for some boneheaded reason. Instead, you need to use a `TextWriter` to get the output:

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        using (TextWriter writer = new Utf8StringWriter(sb))
        {
            xdoc.Save(writer);
        }
        var xmlString = sb.ToString();
```

FWIW, this is why you should name your `XDocument` variable something like `xdoc` rather than `writer`. For one, `XDocument` doesn't actually "write" anything, but also, `writer` is generally reserved for actual "writers" like `TextWriter`. That's all semantic, of course, but especially when dealing with XML, which usually involves voluminous amounts of code, you want it to be as readable and understandable as possible.

One last little tip. When building XML in the way I've shown here, you can pass actual enumerables just as well as single items. For example, let's say you created your list of channel items separately, such that you have a `List<XElement>` called `items`. You can actually just do:

```
new XElement("channel",
    new XElement("title", "My Awesome Channel"),
    new XElement("link", "https://foo.com/rss"),
    new XElement("description", "Best channel ever!"),
    items
)
```

**EDIT**

I completely forgot about `Utf8StringWriter`. That's a derived class of `StringWriter`, because `StringWriter` stupidly returns UTF16, and there's no way to modify that without deriving from it. The implementation is simple, but you'll need to add this to your project:

```
internal sealed class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public Utf8StringWriter(StringBuilder sb)
        : base(sb)
    {
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

If you want to put this in a class library or something and share it between projects, just change `internal` to `public`.